# Functions properties

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a question as such:
[image]

and I need help with the following sub questions. I am not good with functions and I'll appreciate if anyone can find out my mistake.

```
(i) Yes, it does.
(ii) Yes, it does.
(iii) Yes, it does.
(iv) range of f = (1,2,7,1)
     range of g = (1,2,3)
     range of h = (1,3,4,2)
(v) f has an inverse function because it is one to one
    g has no inverse function because it is not one to one
    h has an inverse function because it is one to one
(vi) #im ok from here on
```

i wasn't sure if i did part (i) to (iv) correctly and I'll appreciate if anyone could point out my mistake if i have one.

Comment: What is $g(3)$?

Answer (score 1):

(ii) is incorrect: recall the definition

> A set $f$ of ordered pairs is a function $f:A\to B$ is and only if for all $a\in A$ there is *exactly one* $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$ and all the pairs of $f$ are in $A\times B$.

It is not satisfied by $G$.

(iv): the range is a set, not an ordered tuple, thus it uses the notation $\{a,b,c\}$ (instead of $(a,b,c)$). And, in that notation, repeated elements make no sense.

Comment: Might I suggest you expand on _why_ (ii) was incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

A relation $F\subseteq A\times B$ is a function if and only if for each $x\in A$ there is exactly one $y\in B$ such that $(x,y)\in F$, also written $F(x)=y$.